# optimize Table Spool in SQL Server Execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have the following sql query and trying to optimize it using execution plan. In execution plan it says Estimated subtree cost is 36.89. There are several table spools(Eager Spool). can anyone help me to optimize this query. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT bp.P_ID) AS total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bc.Description != 'S' THEN bp.P_ID END) AS m_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bc.Description = 'S' THEN bp.P_ID END) AS s_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN bc.Description IS NULL THEN bp.P_ID END) AS n_count
FROM 
    progress_tbl AS progress
INNER JOIN  Person_tbl AS bp  ON bp.P_ID = progress.person_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Status_tbl AS bm  ON bm.MS_ID = bp.MembershipStatusID          
LEFT OUTER  JOIN  Membership_tbl AS m ON m.M_ID = bp.CurrentMembershipID
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Category_tbl AS bc ON bc.MC_ID = m.MembershipCategoryID
WHERE 
    logged_when BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see `b` alias. neither I see `b_p` alias used in SELECT part. Something wrong with the posted query

Comment: I have edited the query before post it. I'll change it accordingly

Comment: As you have now provided a working query see my edit

Answer (score 3):

Here's a technique you can use.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                  WHEN bc.Description != 'S' THEN 'M'
                  WHEN bc.Description = 'S' THEN 'S'
                  WHEN bc.Description IS NULL THEN 'N'
                END AS type,
                bp.P_ID
FROM   progress_tbl AS progress
       INNER JOIN Person_tbl AS bp
         ON bp.P_ID = progress.person_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Status_tbl AS bm
         ON bm.MS_ID = bp.MembershipStatusID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Membership_tbl AS m
         ON m.M_ID = bp.CurrentMembershipID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Category_tbl AS bc
         ON bc.MC_ID = m.MembershipCategoryID
WHERE  logged_when BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31' 
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P_ID) AS total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type= 'M' THEN P_ID END) AS m_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type= 'S' THEN P_ID END) AS s_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type= 'N' THEN P_ID END) AS n_count
FROM T
```

I will demonstrate it on a simpler example.

Suppose your existing query is

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT number) AS total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN name != 'S' THEN number END) AS m_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN name = 'S' THEN number END) AS s_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN number END) AS n_count
FROM master..spt_values;
```

You can rewrite it as follows

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                  WHEN name != 'S'
                    THEN 'M'
                  WHEN name = 'S'
                    THEN 'S'
                  ELSE 'N'
                END AS type,
                number
FROM   master..spt_values 
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT number) AS total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type= 'M' THEN number END) AS m_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type= 'S' THEN number END) AS s_count,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type= 'N' THEN number END) AS n_count
FROM T
```

Note the rewrite is costed as considerably cheaper and the plan is much simpler.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. tried your one, It reduces subtree cost 36.98 to 26.87. Do you think we can not optimize this further or because of data we can not further reduce the subtree cost?

Comment: @KapilaPerera - Not possible to say as it will depend on the execution plan for the joins and `WHERE` and the plan you have shown doesn't include those. That would be a different question anyway. The question you asked here was about getting rid of the spools.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, there seems to be some typo/copy paste issues with your query. This makes it rather difficult for us to figure out what's going on.

The table-spools probably are what's going on in the `CASE WHEN b.description etc...` constructions. MSSQL first creates a (memory) table with all the resulting values and then that one gets sorted and streamed through the `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` operator. I don't think there is much you can do about that as the work needs to be done somewhere.

Anyway, some remarks and wild guesses:

- I'm guessing that `logged_when` is in the `progress_tbl` table?
- If so, do you really need to LEFT OUTER JOIN all the other tables? From what I can tell they aren't being used?
- You're trying to count the number of `P_ID`s that match the criteria and you want to split up that number between those that have `b.Description` either 'S', something else, or NULL.

  - for this you could calculate the total as the sum of the m_count, s_count and n_count. This would save you 1 `COUNT()` operation, not sure it helps a lot in the bigger picture but all bits help I guess.

Something like this:

```
;WITH counts AS (

                    SELECT
                        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b.Description != 'S' THEN b_p.P_ID END) AS m_count,
                        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b.Description = 'S' THEN b_p.P_ID END) AS s_count,
                        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b.Description IS NULL THEN b_p.P_ID END) AS n_count
                    FROM 
                        progress_tbl AS progress
                    INNER JOIN  Person_tbl AS bp  ON bp.P_ID = progress.person_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Status_tbl AS bm  ON bm.MS_ID = bp.MembershipStatusID     -- really needed?
                    LEFT OUTER  JOIN  Membership_tbl AS m ON m.M_ID = bp.CurrentMembershipID   -- really needed?
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Category_tbl AS bc ON bc.MC_ID = m.MembershipCategoryID   -- really needed?
                    WHERE 
                        logged_when BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31' -- what table does logged_when column come from????

    )

SELECT total = m_count + s_count + n_count,
       *
  FROM counts
```

## *UPDATE*

BEWARE: Using the answer/example code of Martin Smith I came to realize that `total` isn't necessarily the sum of the other fields. It could be a given `P_ID` shows up with different `description` which then might fall into different categories. Depending on your data it might thus be that my answer is plain wrong.

Comment: progress table has the column logged_when

Comment: bc.Description is using in select query so I need to use Category_tbl. to access the Category_tbl I need rest of the tables to join.

Comment: Im using LEFT OUTER JOIN to get non matching rows in bc.Description == null to get non members